# Using Mathematica to know the number primes that are contained in a given interval

Tags: mathematica

So I want to know basically how to determine how many prime numbers (integers that can only be divided by 1 and themselves) are contained in a given interval.

Thank you.

Comment: There's a [Mathematica SX site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) where this type of question might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are integers, with $a$ composite, then the number of primes in the interval $[a,b]$ is the number of primes less than or equal to $b$ minus the number of primes less than or equal to $a$. If $a$ itself is prime, we should account for this by adding that one prime back on. To determine the number of primes less than or equal to a  number in mathematica we use the command `PrimePi[number]`.

We can program this as follows:

```
numPrimes[m_Integer, n_Integer] := If[PrimeQ[m],
  PrimePi[n] - PrimePi[m] + 1,
  PrimePi[n] - PrimePi[m]
];
numPrimes[11, 31]
numPrimes[10, 31]
numPrimes[555,666]

(* Out: 
  7
  7
  20
*)
```

If you're new to Mathematica, you can also use the WolframAlpha interface, which (in principle) allows you to ask your question in English.

[image]

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: There are a few issues, which I tried to address in an edit (as is very common on stackexchange) - not sure why you rolled it back? First, the answer is incorrect if the smaller number is prime itself: `PrimePi[7] - PrimePi[5]` returns 1, but there are two primes in that closed interval. Second, there's a standard way to post code that allows users to copy it, which an image does not. Finally, why are you using Mathematica's WolframAlpha interface?

Comment: @MarkMcClure 1) Yes, you're right; I assumed in that $a$ is not a prime, so your code is more efficient. 2) I posted an image just as an example but I used the `<code></code>` command to write the code. 3) I don't know.

Anyway, thank you so much and cheers!

Comment: It's not a question of efficiency - it's a question of correctness. I hope you don't mind if I make another edit. Again, that's quite common on the StackExchange network - even assumed.

Comment: I went ahead and made the edit. I hope you appreciate it. Notice that I'm not typing Mathematica code at the WolframAlpha prompt, but an actual English language question.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thank you for your effort! Just a question: what did you mean by that I'm using Mathematica's WolframAlpha interface? Is there another interface? Sorry for being still new to mathematica.

Comment: In your original answer, you posted [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0bFlZ.jpg) that contained an equals sign outlined in an orange triangle. That indicates that you're accessing Mathematica's short WA interface by pushing the equals sign button once at the beginning of a standard Input cell. The result is a single, simple interpretation of your input - in your case, just exactly what you typed in the first place. Note that you could just as easily have typed `= prime pi 33 - prime pi 11`, even though that's not standard Mathematica syntax for what you were trying to type.